# multiply matrices in loop in C

Tags: c, r, matrix

I am attempting to multiply several matrices using a loop in `C`.  I obtain the expected answer in `R`, but cannot obtain the expected answer in `C`.  I suspect the problem is related to the `+=` function which seems to double the value of the product after the first iteration of the loop.

I am not very familiar with `C` and have not been able to replace the `+=` function with one that will return the expected answer.

Thank you for any advice.

First, here is the `R` code that returns the expected answer:

```
B0 = -0.40
B1 =  0.20

mycov1 = exp(B0 + -2 * B1) / (1 + exp(B0 + -2 * B1))
mycov2 = exp(B0 + -1 * B1) / (1 + exp(B0 + -1 * B1))
mycov3 = exp(B0 +  0 * B1) / (1 + exp(B0 +  0 * B1))
mycov4 = exp(B0 +  1 * B1) / (1 + exp(B0 +  1 * B1))

trans1 = matrix(c(1 - 0.25 - mycov1,     mycov1,   0.25 * 0.80,              0,
                                  0,   1 - 0.50,             0,    0.50 * 0.75,
                                  0,          0,             1,              0,
                                  0,          0,             0,              1), 
               nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

trans2 = matrix(c(1 - 0.25 - mycov2,     mycov2,   0.25 * 0.80,              0,
                                  0,   1 - 0.50,             0,    0.50 * 0.75,
                                  0,          0,             1,              0,
                                  0,          0,             0,              1), 
               nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

trans3 = matrix(c(1 - 0.25 - mycov3,     mycov3,   0.25 * 0.80,              0,
                                  0,   1 - 0.50,             0,    0.50 * 0.75,
                                  0,          0,             1,              0,
                                  0,          0,             0,              1), 
               nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

trans4 = matrix(c(1 - 0.25 - mycov4,     mycov4,   0.25 * 0.80,              0,
                                  0,   1 - 0.50,             0,    0.50 * 0.75,
                                  0,          0,             1,              0,
                                  0,          0,             0,              1), 
               nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

trans2b <- trans1  %*% trans2
trans3b <- trans2b %*% trans3
trans4b <- trans3b %*% trans4
trans4b

#
# This is the expected answer
#
#            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.01819965 0.1399834 0.3349504 0.3173467
# [2,] 0.00000000 0.0625000 0.0000000 0.7031250
# [3,] 0.00000000 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000
# [4,] 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000
#
```

Here is my `C` code.  The `C` code is fairly long because I do not know `C` well enough to be efficient:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

char quit;

int main(){

int i, j, k, ii, jj, kk ;

double B0, B1, mycov ;

double trans[4][4]     = {0} ;

double prevtrans[4][4] = {{1,0,0,0},
                          {0,1,0,0},
                          {0,0,1,0},
                          {0,0,0,1}};

B0 = -0.40 ;
B1 =  0.20 ;

for (i=1; i <= 4; i++) {

          mycov = exp(B0 + B1 * (-2+i-1)) / (1 + exp(B0 + B1 * (-2+i-1))) ;

          trans[0][0] =     1 - 0.25 - mycov ;
          trans[0][1] =                mycov ;
          trans[0][2] =          0.25 * 0.80 ;
          trans[0][3] =                    0 ;

          trans[1][0] =                    0 ;
          trans[1][1] =             1 - 0.50 ;
          trans[1][2] =                    0 ;
          trans[1][3] =          0.50 * 0.75 ;

          trans[2][0] =                    0 ;
          trans[2][1] =                    0 ;
          trans[2][2] =                    1 ;
          trans[2][3] =                    0 ;

          trans[3][0] =                    0 ;
          trans[3][1] =                    0 ;
          trans[3][2] =                    0 ;
          trans[3][3] =                    1 ;

          for (ii=0; ii<4; ii++){

               for(jj=0; jj<4; jj++){

                    for(kk=0; kk<4; kk++){

                         trans[ii][jj] += trans[ii][kk] * prevtrans[kk][jj] ;

                    }
               }
          }

          prevtrans[0][0] =     trans[0][0] ;
          prevtrans[0][1] =     trans[0][1] ;
          prevtrans[0][2] =     trans[0][2] ;
          prevtrans[0][3] =     trans[0][3] ;
          prevtrans[1][0] =     trans[1][0] ;
          prevtrans[1][1] =     trans[1][1] ;
          prevtrans[1][2] =     trans[1][2] ;
          prevtrans[1][3] =     trans[1][3] ;
          prevtrans[2][0] =     trans[2][0] ;
          prevtrans[2][1] =     trans[2][1] ;
          prevtrans[2][2] =     trans[2][2] ;
          prevtrans[2][3] =     trans[2][3] ;
          prevtrans[3][0] =     trans[3][0] ;
          prevtrans[3][1] =     trans[3][1] ;
          prevtrans[3][2] =     trans[3][2] ;
          prevtrans[3][3] =     trans[3][3] ;

}

  printf("To close this program type 'quit' and hit the return key\n");
  printf("               \n");
  scanf("%d", &quit);

  return 0;

}
```

Here is the final matrix returned by the above `C` code:

```
0.4821  3.5870  11.68  381.22
0       1       0      76.875
0       0       5      0
0       0       0      5
```

Comment: There is a general dictum here at SO that asking for debugging help requires that a minimal, complete, and verifiable example demonstrating the bug be given.  I suspect that in the process of narrowing down the code to such an example the bug will become easy to spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
                     trans[ii][jj] += trans[ii][kk] * prevtrans[kk][jj] ;
```

is not right. You're modifying `trans` in place while you are still using it to compute the resultant matrix. You need another matrix to store the result of the multiplication temporarily. And then use:

```
      // Store the resultant matrix in temp.
      for (ii=0; ii<4; ii++){

           for(jj=0; jj<4; jj++){

                temp[ii][jj] = 0.0;

                for(kk=0; kk<4; kk++){

                     temp[ii][jj] += trans[ii][kk] * prevtrans[kk][jj] ;

                }
           }
      }

      // Transfer the data from temp to trans
      for (ii=0; ii<4; ii++){

           for(jj=0; jj<4; jj++){
                trans[ii][jj] = temp[ii][jj];
           }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I am not sure why the first line of the final matrix differs between `R` and `C`.  Perhaps I made a mistake when assigning values.  Here is the first line returned by `C`: `0.0182 0.1177 0.2891 0.3770`.  Here is the first line returned by `R`: `0.0182 0.1400 0.3349 0.3173`.

Comment: @MarkMiller, since I don't know R, I can't answer that question.

Comment: If I use `temp[ii][jj] += prevtrans[ii][kk] * trans[kk][jj] ;` then the answers from `C` and `R` match.

Comment: @MarkMiller, Glad you got your answer. This is the well known row major vs column major storage problem. I had to deal with these differences while I was transitioning from FORTAN77 to C/C++.